Is fitting a curve through the ytm of UST bonds a par curve?

I'm wondering if fitting a curve through the yields given from market prices for bonds represents a par curve?

I've seen this question which is similar: Deriving the par-yield curve
My understanding is that the par curve should essentially represent the governments funding cost. If they were to issue a new bond, it's coupon and maturity should lie exactly on the par curve.
Would fitting a curve through the ytm of the most liquid UST bonds represent a par curve? And then zero rates could be derived from this curve? Or is this not the case? The issue I see with it is that it doesnt account for the coupon on the bond, so it definitely can't be equivalent to the typical approach of bootstrapping zero rates using a bonds price, maturity and coupons and then deriving a par curve. But it also seems intuitive to think that the best approximation of where the government would issue a new bond at the same maturity as an existing benchmark would be at that bonds existing ytm.

Bonds are usually issued slightly less than par. Further, as bonds trade their prices can move materially away from par. Therefore, creating a par curve is usually done by first deriving a zero coupon curve (from a set of bonds, could be a susbset) and then implying out what certain tenor bonds would yield to be consistent with the calibration, to achieve a price of 100.
